# Merge different issues on github

Tags: git, github

Sometimes the developers open new issues regarding the same subject.

It will be great to have the possibility to merge the issues.

If it is possible in github, how can I do it?

If not, what is the best way to link different issues?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Currently, the simplest way to resolve this situation is to pick one of the issues to be the main one (whether the best documented, oldest, or whatever). Then, add a comment to the other issues linking to the main issue and close the duplicates.

[Here's an example.](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/789)

[Here's another showing the "Duplicate of #123" syntax.](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/637)

Alternatively, you can leave the issues open and reference them all together in your commit messages: [Example.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2731)

I imagine that in the future, the team behind GitHub will make this process easier.

Comment: The comment should be of the form "Duplicate of #123" or otherwise contain "#" followed by the issue number, then Github will automatically link to issue 123 (no need for copying URLs around).

Comment: This isn't ideal because it doesn't automatically merge in all the subscribers from the duplicate issue.

Comment: @fmoo: True, but when you add the comment to the duplicate issue the subscribers will receive notification and can then subscribe to the main issue.

Comment: In addition to this we use github's new task markdown syntax to create subtask on issues. Example - https://github.com/rtCamp/buddypress-media/issues/28

Comment: The problem with adding a comment is that it isn't obvious from the summary page, so it's possible to confuse the issue as being solved. To fix that I use a label so it's visible from the summary page, and I know that any bug that's closed and labeled duplicate isn't necessarily resolved.

Comment: "Duplicate of #"  is now the official GitHub keyword https://github.com/blog/2398-manage-issues-and-pull-requests-with-keyword-updates

Comment: Is there features request section for github, for tell him to add this feature?

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. It's already implemented as noted in the comment above yours: https://github.com/blog/2398-manage-issues-and-pull-requests-with-keyword-updates

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ The duplicate is not marge, Imagine having someone question on one issue, and the other person inadvertently or unknowingly opens another issue to answer another one. Marking as a duplicate is not useful here, and both issues need to be marged and integrated.